# TIMEDIFF GROUP BY involved days

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for a way to get the TIMEDIFF of two timestamps grouped by involved days in MySQL.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-01-02 10:00:00', '2012-01-01 10:00:00');
```

This is just giving the diff of 24 hours.

I need the diff of both (or maybe more) days. i.e.:

```
2012-01-01: 14:00:00
2012-01-02: 10:00:00
[...]
```

Is there a way to group in the TIMEDIFF function?

Comment: to clarify: you want to go through a list of datetimes and get the diff between each one (i.e. between 1 and 2, 2 and 3 etc)?

Comment: no, I just have two timestamps timestamp1 (2012-01-01...) and timestamp2 (2012-01-09...). The result should be a list of the dates from 1st to 9th of Jan and the proportionate hours / minutes / seconds.

Comment: ah, please post the desired output in your question, so that we can better assist you

Comment: You will need a stored procedure to loop between these 2 dates. I unswered [a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14287289/913097) sometime ago.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want, you need to generate a sequence of numbers.  Perhaps you have a table.  If not, something like the following:

```
select dstart + interval n.num days
from (select d1*10+d2 as num
      from (select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
            select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
            select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) d1 cross join
           (select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
            select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
            select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) d2
      ) n join
      (select date('2012-01-02') as dend, date('2012-01-01') dstart
      on dstart + interval n.num days <= dend
```

(This is not tested, so it might have syntax errors.)